# Codec Not Found

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing, codec, avi

I'm trying to read a AVI file into MATLAB using VideoReader.

```
video = VideoReader('test.avi');
```

But get this error:

```
 The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:
    cvid

Error in VideoReader (line 147)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in video (line 1)
    video = VideoReader('test.avi');
```

The cvid codec is installed on my win7 64bit box. Any help? I am required to use VideoReader.

EDIT: MATLAB version is 2013a

Comment: cvid is Cinepak (http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)

Comment: @Daniel yup, I have Cinepak already on my system, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/7150-avi-codec-issues-in-64-bit-windows-7-environment), [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93175) and also the document on `aviwriter` which specifies that you can use "'Cinepak' on 32-bit systems.", I think the issue is with the combination of that specific codec and your 64 bit version of MATLAB. You probably have software on your computer which can handle 32 bit codecs so will be able to view it with some video player software, but MATLAB will be looking for the 64 bit codec (which for Cinepak is non-existent).

Your options would seem to be:

1. Convert the file to another codec or to an uncompressed version.
2. Install or get access to a 32-bit version of MATLAB